# Как сделать что бы галерея от magnific popup работала лишь на мобильном?

Tags: javascript, popup, magnific

подскажите пожалуйста создал такую структуру

И сам JS код

```
$('#gallery').magnificPopup({
    delegate: 'a',
    type: 'image',
    tLoading: 'Loading image #%curr%...',
    mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
    gallery: {
      enabled: true,
      navigateByImgClick: true,
      preload: [0,1] // Will preload 0 - before current, and 1 after the current image
    },

  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|BB|PlayBook|IEMobile|Windows Phone|Kindle|Silk|Opera Mini/i)){
  //тут код
}
```